# Why does VirtualBox even need GuestAdditions to resize the guest window

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have struggled with VirtualBox for quite a while, sometimes guest additions installs nicely and everything works, sometimes, like now, I end up with a tiny little window to configure CentOS 7 with and spend all day searching forums and staring wide-eyed at my monitor.

All I really need guest additions for is to resize the screen to a reasonable size. My question is, what is the reason that the guest additions iso is necessary to resize the screen? What specifically does it provide that allows the screen to be resized? And, if it's not too off-topic, why am I charged with doing this manually each time?

I'm using Fedora 26 as host and Virtualbox 5.1.24

Comment: Ubuntu guest with guest additions works fine so I'm saving myself some grief by using it to ssh into guests that don't acknowledge guest additions as a reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it needs to communicate the virtual screen resolution back down from the host window size to the VM. This requires some intelligence between the host and guest. It's basically setting up a "proper" graphics card and monitor rather than relying on "basic" devices built into Windows.

Without the Guest Additions the guest can only assume that the "standard" screen resolutions are available and the host window size is determined by the guest resolution as set in the guest "Display Properties" panel.

With the guest additions it can correctly set the panel "native resolution" (host window size) and let the guest OS reset itself to the right resolution.

Comment: But the new VirtualBox version does not require Guest Additions. I tried it with tails.

Comment: Tails probably has the guest additions built in to it. A lot of Linux versions now integrate it by default.

Comment: BTW, why hyper does not require that type of extra software to make VM full screen?

Comment: Because to make it full screen it doesn't need to do anything more than have the emulated monitor pass down the real monitors native resolution. Full screen is easy but having to take account of the "monitor" being any random resolution while the system is live without constantly unplugging and replugging a virtual monitor (when the window size changes) is hard.